# Moment Format Returns different values in backend / frontend code

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, formatdatetime

Does `moment(date).format('LL')` return different values based on locale / timezone?

On my backend I'm getting: `October 24, 2022` and on my frontend I'm getting `24 October 2022`.

What can I do to ensure moment will return the same value regardless of timezone / locale?

I need it in a user friendly format, which is why I'm not using an ISO string.

Comment: You're using an _explicitly_ localised format, per https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ What's user-friendly depends on your user's expectations.

Comment: You should use local like this: "moment().locale('de').format('LL')"

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by using `.format('MMMM D, YYYY')` instead